# NotoSansTelugu font is not supporting in iOS 15 and iOS 16 versions

Tags: ios, swift, localization, locale

I added language support feature in my app. For all the languages I'm using different-different fonts. I added the .ttf file in app and in Info.plist also. I checked in Build phase - Copy Bundle Resource there also It's present.

**Localisable file I added for telugu language:**

```
"newsletter" = "సమాచార పత్రిక(న్యూస్‌లెట్టర్)";

"darkMode" = "డార్క్ మోడ్";
```

**This is for when we're selecting the language from UI then we're storing in UserDefaults:**

```
func saveSelectedLanguage() {
    for language in languages where selectedLanguage == language.languageText {
        UserDefaults.appLanguage = language.languageCode
    }
}
```

**I'm fetching the language localisation file by passing the selected language code:**

```
class LanguageManager: LanguageProvider {
    func fetchValue(for key: Localize.Key) -> String {
        var savedAppLanuage = UserDefault.appLanguage
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: savedAppLanuage, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path ?? "")
        return NSLocalizedString(key.rawValue, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle ?? Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}




/// Property wrapper to get the actual localized string from localized file
    @propertyWrapper
    public struct LocalizedString {
        var key: Localize.Key
        let languageManager: LanguageProvider = LanguageManager()
        public var wrappedValue: String {
            languageManager.fetchValue(for: key)
//            NSLocalizedString(key.rawValue, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

**Fonts I'm using in my app:**

```
enum AppFontName {
    case roboto
    case notoSansDevanagari
    case notoSansKannada
    case notoSansTelugu
    
    var value: String {
        switch self {
        case .roboto: return "Roboto-Regular"
        case .notoSansDevanagari: return "NotoSansDevanagari-Regular"
        case .notoSansKannada: return "NotoSansKannada-Regular"
        case .notoSansTelugu: return "NotoSansTelugu-Regular"
        }
    }
```

First time when I'm launching the app and selecting the telugu language then the incorrect text is showing but in console the text is showing correct. When I'm killing the app and relaunch then the text is coming correct. I'm using NotoSansTelugu.
(Regular, Bold, Medium, Light and Thin).

For hindi I'm using NoToSansDevanagari and that is working fine. Only the problem with telugu.

In iOS14 and iOS17+ version it's working. Only the issue with iOS 15 and iOS 16.

I tried two things:

1. I deleted the fonts and again I added.
2. I reinstalled the fonts and added in my app.

But still it's not working. The correct text is not rendering in the app. But if I'm killing the app and relaunching then it's working.

**In console the text is translating properly but in UI it's not rendering properly**

In my app I'm using both swift and swiftUI

Xcode version: 15.0

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue. Thank in advance!

[Screenshot of telugu incorrect text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5rRc.png)

[Screenshot of list of correct text of telugu language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfHO2.png)

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Install the app and select telugu language and click on apply then next page will come. Verify it the data is correct.
2. Kill the app and relaunch it again select the telugu and apply. You'll see some the text is incorrect.

**In this Sample project, the text is rendering properly at first launch and after killing the app and relaunching then it's not rendering properly(showing text incorrect). But in my older project it's working as vice versa(the text is not rendering properly but in console it's showing correct text at first launch and after killing the app and relaunching then it's working). But issue is same. Text is not coming correctly. For reference you can check the code and screenshot also. Thank you in advance!**

*Git repo:*

[fontIssue.git](https://github.com/swarna456/fontIssue.git)

Comment: What do you mean by "when I'm launching the app and selecting the telugu language." There is no supported way to "select" any language inside of an app. You can select language in Settings. Having the app update correctly when Locale changes is an app coding issue, and you haven't provided any code to help us debug it.  I recommend creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I added the custom language selection UI in my app. So, Once the user launch the app I'm showing the language selection option i.e Hindi, English and Telugu. After selecting the language the main screen is coming. But there the text is showing incorrect. But if I'm selecting hindi or telugu then correct text is coming. Even if I'm relaunching the app then correct text is coming for telugu also.

Comment: The MCVE is definitely the right direction here. You have a mistake in your app, and simplifying it is how you're going to find that mistake. Right now it probably feels like it's impossible for there to be a mistake. Creating a MCVE will help you find it anyway.

Comment: I have provided the code. Can you please take a look. @RobNapier

Comment: This is not an MCVE; no one can reproduce your problem with the code you've provided. But if this is the minimal code, then you have the tools you need to debug this. Put exactly what you've described in a tiny program that **only** does this. Then put breakpoints at `languageManager.fetchValue(for: key)`. My expectation is that it does not do what you expect. It is conceivable that there is an obscure OS-level bug that specifically has difficulty with Telugu, but much more likely you have a small bug in your code or configuration. Make your project tiny and debug on that.

Comment: I created the sample app and the shared the link including the screenshot of incorrect and correct text. Can you please check it once. Thanks @RobNapier

Comment: That link returns a 404 error. I suspect you haven't made it public.

Comment: Can you try again. I've provided the permission to you. Thanks @RobNapier

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Everyone who reads this question needs access to the sample project. Is that the case? Otherwise, this is a consulting engagement, not a stack overflow question.

Comment: I shared the another git repo. Can you please check it. @RobNapier

Comment: Can you please take a look. This is very urgent for me. @RobNapier

Comment: I'll probably look at it some more over the weekend. It's an interesting question, but I'm busy today. My current suspicion is that it's probably a bug in iOS and is worth opening a Feedback about (possibly a TSI). But I'm wondering if there is supposed to be a ZWJ (or possibly ZWNJ?) in పత్రిక. I'm studying the Unicode spec on reph (https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/ch12.pdf page 518). It's likely your encoding is correct (since this ర isn't initial), and the rendering engine is just buggy, but that's the part that's got me wondering. I'm just becoming familiar with Telugu.

Comment: It would also be very helpful if you spelled out exactly what the problem is, perhaps walking through the example of పత్రిక (pa ta virama ra i ka). I don't actually read Telugu, and I'm having trouble identifying the second character in the "incorrect" image. What vowel is on the త? Can you walk through precisely what characters are being displayed and what characters you expect? I understand how Telugu combining characters work in Unicode, but I don't don't actually know the language.

Comment: I also recommend removing the Google fonts from the problem. Does this reproduce using the system fonts? If it's only with this font, the font may be buggy, and you'd want to talk with Google.

Comment: As you mentioned that you're unable to identify the second character of incorrect text, because that character is not belongs to telugu that character is wrongly displayed in the screen and I'm expecting this "త్రి" character.  

I'm using Noto fonts for all three languages i.e. Hindi, Kannada and Telugu but for telugu only the font is not working properly.  I tried with system font i.e. "Kohinoor telugu" but this issue is not reproducible for that.

Comment: ah, this helpful. That does sound like a font bug then. Modern fonts are basically small (and sometimes large) programs. They can have bugs just like any software. A quick search for "noto telugu bug" turns up many issues over the last decade. I would open an issue here: https://github.com/notofonts/telugu

Comment: But I used NotoSans font. For NotoSerifTelugu it's working fine.

Comment: That link is for both NotoSansTelugu and NotoSerifTelegu (see the Sources directory; it bundles both of them). The fact that it's one variant of one specific font definitely suggests the bug is in the font.

Comment: But on that issue there is no comment or solution.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to discuss with the team to explore the bug if you've demonstrated it's related to one font and not others. That's the ideal forum for that.

Comment: Yes, I added the issue. https://github.com/notofonts/telugu/issues/23